# Error in Simu5g and Veins5.2 make on the Omnetpp IDE

Tags: clang, omnet++, veins, lld

I am getting the following error in Simu5g make on Terminal.
`libsimu5g.so` file is not build at the end.

> Creating shared library: ../out/clang-release/src/libsimu5g.so
> ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lINET
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:407: ../out/clang-release/src/libsimu5g.so] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ash/simu5g/omnetpp-6.0/myworkspace/simu5g-master/simu5g/src'
> make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2

Veins 5.2 is being build properly, however, there is no `libveins.so` file after build.
How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you done all steps from [Simu5g Install Guide](http://simu5g.org/install.html)? In particular, have you compiled INET?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have installed all the prerequisites, I am stuck on step 4 from Building from the OMNeT++ IDE

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer:

Ensure that Build Configuration is constant all along.

Inet should be build with debug and release options.

Select Inet -> select Project Features -> C/C++ Build -> In configuration, select [All Configurations] in dropdown -> Apply and close

Then right click on Inet -> Build Configuration -> Build Selected -> select debug and release -> ok

Repeat the build procedure with Veins and Simu5g